# How to call a DRPC Storm from PHP?

Tags: php, rpc, apache-storm

Consider a storm DRPC topology which is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder builder = new LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder("exclamation");  
    builder.addBolt(new ExclamationBolt()); 
    Config conf = new Config();  
    try {
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("exclaim", conf, builder.createRemoteTopology());
    } catch (AlreadyAliveException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidTopologyException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Tested with `LocalCluster` i.e `drpc.execute("exclamation", "aaa")`, it works. But question is how to call remotely from the PHP?

---

**Update**: I had installed [thrift](http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-apache-thrift) and generated the PHP by running `thrift --gen php storm.thrift` & got a gen-php directory with a bunch of php classes.

Could anyone give an example or link showing implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to write an abstraction layer on top of the generated class files, exactly like the [java client](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/master/src/jvm/backtype/storm/utils/DRPCClient.java).

You can generate the drpc class files by:

```
thrift --gen php storm.thrift
```

and you have to require the php-thrift library in your code.

I have put the working code here in below repo:

https://github.com/mithunsatheesh/php-drpc